# Inserting Values into CTE

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a temp table in postgres using some values.
Looking for help in creating the syntax.

Example data from csv

```
id sale
1 2321
2 143
3 1
4 233
5 123
```

I'm looking for if there is a way to import the csv into CTE
or
writing out all the data in syntax

Comment: No, you can't import CSV in a CTE. You can use a `COPY` command though. Did you try defining the temporary table?

Comment: You can only insert into **tables**

Comment: No. I was hoping I could do some quick import. I lack access, so it seems like hard coding the data is the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use file_fdw (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/file-fdw.html) to read the CSV file in as a table, or you can hardcode the values if you're only using a small set of data.

e.g.

```
WITH csvdata (id, sale) AS (
  VALUES (1, 2321),
    (2, 143),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 233)
)
SELECT *
FROM csvdata...
```